# Error when pulling data using JIRA Rest API based on created date

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to query data using JIRA Rest API and trying to pull data based on `created` date.

Given below is what I am trying but it throws an error

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=True&startAt=0&validateQuery=True&maxResults=50

text: Error in the JQL Query: 'True' is a reserved JQL word. You must surround it in quotation marks to use it in a query. (line 1, character 1)
```

This is what I am trying to query:

```
jira = jira_login <- Establishes connection to JIRA Rest API
issues = jira.search_issues("created" >= '2020-06-01')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that

```
issues = jira.search_issues("created" >= '2020-06-01')
```

evaluates to true (since the >= is outside the quotes, python will evaluate it, and then pass `True` to the function.

Try this:

```
issues = jira.search_issues("created >= \"2020-06-01\"")
```